# Gradle won't import jargs from repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have this import in my code

```
import jargs.gnu.CmdLineParser;
```

My build.gradle has this in it's "dependencies"

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jargs/jargs
compile group: 'jargs', name: 'jargs', version: '1.0'
```

For all of my other dependencies that are listed, they are imported/downloaded whatever Gradle/Eclipse is doing, but this one just refuses.  I spied this on [the jargs Maven page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jargs/jargs/1.0)

```
Note: this artifact it located at WSO2 Dist repository (http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/)
```

I did some digging around and thought that maybe this package was not on the usual mavenCentral() spot, so I tried adding another url from an example I found in my research

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.onslip:gradle-one-jar:1.0.5
    }
}
```

I did a refresh on my Gradle project through Eclipse, but this hasn't solved anything.  What I'm doing in the interim is manually downloading the jar and sticking it in a "libs" folder and adding

```
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
```

Which gets me where I want to go.  All of the problem areas go away when I flagDir but not doing it through the Maven repo.  I feel like I'm *that* close.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I add the alternate urls to the "repositories" portion, it'll work

```
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    //jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/" }
    /*
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    */
}
```

I guess I need to better understand what the "repositories" is used for and "buildscript" has a "repositories" as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems it seems with your setup on one side and `jargs` on the other side.

For your setup:

- The `buildscript` repositories are used for plugins and their dependencies. That is everything which is needed to setup your build,
- The regular `repositories` are used for fetching dependencies of your code as declared in your build, let's call them project repositories.

So it is normal that you needed to add the specific repository to the project `repositories` instead.

Note that you should not need to add `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/` to project repositories.

About `jargs`:

- Looks like a weird artifact which can be found at different coordinates depending on the repository

  - Your issue contains an URL that indicates that the group is `net.sourceforge.jargs` and not just `jargs` but also that it is not in Maven Central but in a [specific repository](http://maven.nuiton.org/nexus/content/groups/releases/net/sourceforge/jargs/jargs/1.0/jargs-1.0.pom)
  - Your dependency declaration uses the group `jargs` which is indeed valid in that other repository you [link to](http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/jargs/jargs/1.0/).

But all in all that means that `jargs` has different coordinates depending on the repository. I would make sure you use the version recommended by the project.

Comment: the project is ancient (last update 2005), that's why there are multiple circulating repos